# How to add div to frameset and show it

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom, frameset

I have a frames with top menu and bottom content, when I clock menu, I want to add link and script lines as below to frameset's head:

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/maintenance/styles/psi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/maintenance/js/psi.js"></script>
```

two div tags to frameset's body:

```
<div align='center' id='FreezePane' class='FreezePaneOff'><div id='InnerFreezePane' class='InnerFreezePane'></div></div>
```

then call JavaScript function as below to show it:

```
FreezeScreen("Waiting...");
```

I did as below, but not sure how to go next step, may I on the right way? please help me.

```
var frame = document.frames["main"];
var div = document.createElement("div");
var attr = document.createAttribute("align");
attr.value = "center";
div.setAttributeNode(attr);
attr = document.createAttribute("id");
atti.value = "FreezePane";
div.setAttributeNode(attr);
attr = document.createAttribute("class");
atti.value = "FreezePaneOff";
div.setAttributeNode(attr);
frame.body.appendChild(div);
...
```

Comment: frameset? The 90's called, they want their website back :p

Comment: This tool is using by users, I have to maintenance it.

Comment: I'm sorry to read that - you'll need to wait for the "old school" web programmers to wake up, nobody knows how to do framesets any more :p